# RAM usage keeps increasing when the function pcap_sendqueue_transmit

Tags: c++, c, network-programming

I am writing a code to use `pcap_sendqueue_transmit` to transmit packet queues over ethernet.
The software works in two mode. In mode 1 I assemble an array of queues using 
`pcap_createsrcstr()`
`pcap_open()`
`pcap_sendqueue_alloc()`
`pcap_next_ex()`
`pcap_sendqueue_transmit()`
This mode all packets are sent successfully
In mode 2 
I do the same thing bute the the whole lot is in a loop
In this mode the  transmission is OK, but I do not use 
`pcap_sendqueue_destroy()`
`pcap_close()`
as the loops needs to continue.

But i noticed that the RAM usage in the PC is increased within the loop and keeps increasing the following loops.

Any thoughts why the memory is increased at in the following loops?

I do not use an dynamic memory in my code at all, the code is quite big otherwise I would have post it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code at any code board, for example http://codepad.org

Comment: You still need any help?